# How can I call link directive function after controller code has been run

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to render code in the link function after the controller resolves the http call but the link function is called before that. How can I call link after `$scope.menuHtml` has been set?

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="testD" nav-menu-output="parseMenuJsonAndOutPutMenu()"></div>
```

**DIRECTIVE:**

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: ['$scope', '$q','$http', function ($scope, $q,$http) {
        $http.get('ajax/menu' ).then(function (data) {
            $scope.menuHtml = generateHtmlMenu(data);
        });
    }],
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var templateString = scope.menuHtml;
        var compiledTemplate = $compile(templateString)(scope);
        compiledTemplate.appendTo("#testD");
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for i got this problem on my fresher time using angularjs. But i got the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using `scope.$watch()` and rerunning your compiled template code on that. This way you can make as many requests to the menu endpoint as you want and your template will be recompiled.

Here's more information about watch:
[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

Here's an updated version which should work properly:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: ['$scope', '$q','$http', function ($scope, $q,$http) {
        $http.get('ajax/menu' ).then(function (data) {
            $scope.menuHtml = generateHtmlMenu(data);
        });
    }],
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch('menuHtml', function() {
            var templateString = scope.menuHtml;
            var compiledTemplate = $compile(templateString)(scope);
            compiledTemplate.appendTo("#testD");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: hmm. possibly more useful than the other answer

Comment: @FutuToad Just updated with a code snippet. Give that a try (didn't actually run it so there could be minor issues) and see if that works for you. Also, you will need to change the appendTo to something else to prevent duplicates. Maybe use a container div and use .html().

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `async: false`

Please Try this code instead of your code,

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: ['$scope', '$q','$http', function ($scope, $q,$http) {    
     $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax/menu',
        async: false
    }).success(function (data) {
         $scope.menuHtml = generateHtmlMenu(data);
    })}],
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var templateString = scope.menuHtml;
        var compiledTemplate = $compile(templateString)(scope);
        compiledTemplate.appendTo("#testD");
    }    
}
```

Comment: This will, of course, potentially block other rendering. You should stay away from doing these request synchronously, especially in small components which may block others from loading in.

Comment: @bjtitus hmm, even with this way the link still runs first

Comment: did you check it using debugger?

Comment: @RameshRajendran yep I did.